# Adding fractions in base-$8$ as fractions and decimals.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, fractions

I would like to add the following fractions represented in base-$8$ as both fractions and decimals:

> $(\frac{2}{3})_{\text{8}} + (\frac{5}{7})_{\text{8}}$

Please somebody explain to me how to do this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Properties of fractions do not change when it comes to the base:

So if you have $$\frac{2_8}{3_8}+\frac{5_8}{7_8}$$

Use the properties you already know. Get common denominators and add!

$$\frac{2_8}{3_8}+\frac{5_8}{7_8} = \frac{2_8*7_8}{3_8*7_8}+\frac{5_8*3_8}{7_8*3_8} = \frac{16_8}{25_8}+\frac{17_8}{25_8}=\frac{35_8}{25_8} = \frac{29_{10}}{21_{10}}$$

For decimals it is the same. Let's take $\frac{29}{10} = 1.380952381_{10}$... Using the recursive multiplication base method for decimals, first notice that $1.380952381>1$. Mark that down, and subtract 1. Our number now is $$1_8 + 0.380952381_{10}$$

Multiply $.380952381$ by our base, or 8. We get: $8*0.380952381 = 3.04739048$ Notice that $3.04739048>1$. Mark that down, and subtract 3. Our number now is $$1.3_8+0.04739048_{10}$$

Multiply $0.04739048$ by our base, or 8. We get: $8*0.04739048= 0.37912384$ Notice that $0.37912384<1$. Mark that down. Our number now is $$1.30_8+0.37912384_{10}$$

Keep repeating this on and on to your heart's content or until you reach a certian level of accuracy. After 7 iterations I got $$\frac{35_8}{25_8} = 1.30302071_8$$

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Can you also show this in decimal version? @DoveDevic

Comment: Is it not $\frac{41_8}{25_8}$?

Comment: The answer should be $\frac{41_8}{25_8}$

Comment: @kunjimamu, notice that $2_8 = 2_{10}$ and that $3_8 = 3_{10}$ and that $5_8 = 5_{10}$ and that $7_8 = 7_{10}$. With this we can simply add our base 10 fraction to "check" our answer. When you do the addition, you will obtain $\frac{29}{21}$, which then you can easily convert to base 8.

Comment: Why do you believe it should be 41_8 (which is 33_10) rather than 35_8 (which is 29_10).  I've Don e the math and... I don't see that it'd be 41.

Comment: @kunjimamu, The only explanation I may have for the discrepancy might be in how the problem is written... When you write $(\frac{2}{3})_8$ do you mean $\frac{2_8}{3_8}$... or... $(\frac{2_{10}}{3_{10}})_8 = (0.333_{10})_8$? The latter is fairly complicated and nonsensical to say the least, but given this might be from a textbook may not be too far fetched as a question.

Comment: @DoveDevic the results should end with 1.30303030303.....Possible rounding errors caused in your 4th and 5th iterations could have caused the error.

Comment: @ELO My results were just after 7 iterations; if you iterate infinitely, yes, you would be correct!

Comment: Sorry I guess I should of read more into the question and the comments great job!